# Why is there nullability warning for explicitly declared reference return value?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types, nullability

I enabled Nullability context for my test project and tried to fix all nullability warnings. I was able to fix them all except the below one which I don't understand (at `return ref book;` line). I pasted the warning in the comment at this line that the compiler produces:

```
class Program
{
    private Book[] books = { new Book("Call of the Wild, The", "Jack London"),
                    new Book("Tale of Two Cities, A", "Charles Dickens") };
    private Book? nobook = null;

    public ref Book? GetBookByTitle(string title)
    {
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < books.Length; ctr++)
        {
            ref Book book = ref books[ctr];
            if (title == book.Title)
                return ref book; //CS8619: Nullability of reference types in value of type 'Book' doesn't match target type 'Book?'.
        }
        return ref nobook;
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public readonly string Title;
    public readonly string Author;

    public Book(string title, string author)
    {
        Title = title;
        Author = author;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler is not satisfied with the non-nullable variable `ref Book book` that is returned in the method as nullable `ref Book?`

As I know we can assign non-nullable variables to nullable variables and it's presented below. And as the code below shows the compiler doesn't see any problems if I return non-ref `Book book` variable in the method with `Book?` type:

```
    public Book? GetBookCopyByTitle(string title)
    {
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < books.Length; ctr++)
        {
            ref Book book = ref books[ctr];
            if (title == book.Title)
                return book; //no warning here. The compiler is satisfied if we don't use ref return value
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Why the compiler produces in the first code snippet this error:

`Nullability of reference types in value of type 'Book' doesn't match target type 'Book?'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because you are using `ref return`s here.

Recall the meaning of `ref return`s. You are returning the reference to a variable, and the caller can change the value of the variable using the reference.

`GetBookByTitle` is declared to return a nullable reference. According to the declaration, I can get the reference from the method, and then set it to null:

```
ref var book = ref GetBookByTitle("Tale of Two Cities, A");
book = null; // book is nullable, right? GetBookByTitle says it will return a nullable reference
```

Because of the specific title I've passed in, `book = null;` would be reached, setting the *non-nullable* `books[1]` to `null`! If this is allowed, it would break the safety that nullable reference types brings, so it's not allowed.

Comment: oh, I didn't think about such case. Thank you for the explanation!